# phantomjs raise OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

When I use phantomjs in Scrapy middlewares, it sometimes raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 37, in 
process_request
response = yield method(request=request, spider=spider)
File "/home/ttc/ruyi-
scrapy/saibolan/saibolan/hz_webdriver_middleware.py", line 47, in 
 process_request
driver.quit()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 76, in quit
self.service.stop()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 149, in stop
self.send_remote_shutdown_command()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py", line 67, in send_remote_shutdown_command
os.close(self._cookie_temp_file_handle)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

actually it dont appear every time, I crawl 80 pages and it appears 30 times,and this in phantomjs middlewares

```
class HZPhantomjsMiddleware(object):

def __init__(self, settings):
    self.phantomjs_driver_path = settings.get('PHANTOMJS_DRIVER_PATH')
    self.cloud_mode = settings.get('CLOUD_MODE')

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler.settings)

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    # 线上需要 display， 本地调试可以注释掉
    # if self.cloud_mode:
    #     display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    #     display.start()
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
        self.phantomjs_driver_path, desired_capabilities=dcap)
    # chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(request.url)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
            ec.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="txt-box"]|//h4[@class="weui_media_title"]|//div[@class="rich_media_content "]'))
        )
        body = driver.page_source
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.quit()
        return HtmlResponse(request.url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
    except:
        driver.quit()
        spider.logger.error('Ignore request, url: {}'.format(request.url))
        raise IgnoreRequest()
```

I don't know what might lead to this error.

Comment: How are you running the program? It looks like an error with the filesystem, perhaps you are running low on disk space or something else is going on.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I run the program in general scrapy meaning, "scrapy crawl spider --loglevel=INFO --logfile=1.log"

Answer (score 4):

As of July 2016, driver.close() and driver.quit() weren't sufficient for me. That killed the node process but not the phantomjs child process it spawned.

Following the discussion on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/767), the single solution that worked for me was to run:

```
import signal

driver.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM) # kill the specific phantomjs child proc
driver.quit()                                      # quit the node proc
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3216. A suggested workaround (specifying cookies file explicitly) worked for me:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(self.phantomjs_driver_path, desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--cookies-file=/tmp/cookies.txt'])
```